# PHP nesting quotes

Tags: php, quotes, double-quotes

The following fails:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE UserID = '$_SESSION['userID']'");
```

I tried the following:

```
$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE UserID = '$userID'");
```

and it works.  Is there a way to do this without making a separate variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE UserID = '{$_SESSION['userID']}'");
```

Comment: +1 My preferred way of doing it especially when it comes to array elements.

Comment: @RabidFire I actually prefer the other method because i can also also concatenate functions.

Comment: On the other hand, you can't concatenate when using HEREDOC notation ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE UserID = '".$_SESSION['userID']."'");
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE UserID = '{$_SESSION['userID']}'");
```

worth noting it would recommend the first one because it gets easier to read/find when you use a php editor, which in return makes it easier to debugg

Comment: Like Breezer shows here you should jump out of your double quotes and concatenate the variable using dots.

Comment: Just ran a quick test and found that concatenating is about 2% faster than using `{}` :D

Answer (score 0):

Your first chokes the query, because you're actually commanding WHERE `userID` is `'$_SESSION['`.  Not to mentions that rest which is `userID']}'` will be interpreted as a syntax error by MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE UserID = '$_SESSION[userID]'");
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is a very bad way to do that. PHP will try to find a constant named userID and throw a warning if it doesn't. So, yes it will work sometimes, but might fail badly.

Comment: I would say for SESSION values it will work just file. Session values usually mean restricted access.. meaning if you are on this page, you have a session value set. Now in the event it was some GET value that may or may not be set, then its a terrible idea. In more than one way. On that note.. can constants even be defined in a string?